# Hide Button After A Particular Time

Tags: javascript, php

I want to hide a button after a user submits a form. I stored the time the user submitted the form in a database table already. What I want is to disable the button 2 seconds after the user clicks on it.

I am using php to calculate the time difference and javascript to hide the code.

I am not sure if this is correct, but the php code will add 2 seconds to the time the user submits the form and subtract if from the current time.

Here is my code

```
$a = $row_rsGH['time'];
$b = round(microtime(true));
$c = '2000';//--code in milliseconds
$d = ($a+$c)-$b;

<script type="text/javascript">  
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#ghdiv').fadeOut('fast');
}, <?php echo $d; ?>); // <-- time in milliseconds
</script>
```

My aim is that I want the submit button to be hidden, 2 seconds after it is clicked and when i refresh, it won't show

Comment: Ok. So what is the problem? What does `echo $d;` return?

Comment: I don't understand the question either. Do you want or not to hide the button, 2 seconds after the user has clicked on submit?

Comment: I'm sorry I confused things with my question. My aim is that I want the submit button to be hidden, 2 seconds after it is clicked and when i refresh, it won't show

Comment: Is now the button being hidden after 2 seconds? You can use something like `localStorage()` for the refresh part.

Comment: take a look to my answer and you can use cookies or  local storage to remember this click

Comment: Can you please assist? I don't know how to go about using localstorage()

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that amount of complexity. Do it all using js:

```js
document.getElementById("ghdiv").addEventListener("click",function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('#ghdiv').fadeOut('fast');
    },2000);
});
```

```css
button{
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ghdiv">My Button</button>
```

Comment: Hi @Behrad thank you for your answer. If I refresh my page with this, the button still shows

Comment: JavaScript has one `document`, one `getElementById`, one `addEventListener`, one callback mechanism..., This causes similarity in js. But your answer is not correct @mohade. `setInterval` is used to perform periodic tasks, for creating a manual delay in program, you should use `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

when you click button after 2 seconds the button hide if its id=ghdiv

```
    document.getElementById("ghdiv").addEventListener("click",function(){
//you can put here any code to procced after the button clicked
        setInterval(function(){
        $('#ghdiv').fadeOut('fast');
        },20000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use 2 page. 1 with no submit button. and other with submit. so if u click submit then redirect to page with no button.

```
<a href=NextTARGET.php>
```

or use redirect after 5second to file target.php

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5; url=TARGET.php'>
```